# Generating documentation for a Datasnap RESTful API

Tags: api, rest, delphi, documentation-generation, datasnap

I've been looking for a way to include an auto-generated documentation endpoint  to an existing Delphi Datasnap RESTful API.

Can it be done? Are there annotations or external tools I can use?
Where would I begin, how would I proceed? If not from within Delphi itself, can I integrate with e.g. Swagger?

It seems somewhat anachronistic to build a RESTful API without offering a documentation endpoint these days...

Any and all information that could help me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Swagger, via YAML has just been added to Delphi through EMS, the latest RESTful API development option in Delphi.

https://delphiaball.co.uk/2016/04/22/swagger-yaml-delphi/

Its based on Attributes that are added to the API end points as they are defined and that in turn creates the YAML to import into Swagger.

Comment: I ended up writing and using a source file parser that generates YAML or JSON from both the source and XML comment blocks and that works quite nice. It's nice to see that this finally exists in an official form that requires less DIY. Thanks for the link!